# What is the significance of the drawings in the first few pages of "Drops of Melodies"?

Tags: poetry, uyghur-language, drops-of-melodies, hemirah-tohti

*Drops of Melodies* by Hemirah Tohti has the following images in the first couple pages of the Kindle edition:

[image]

[image]

However, I don't see any attribution for these images and don't exactly understand their significance in terms of the overall work. Can someone explain the source and purpose of those?